# Reset back to default state after animation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So here is what I have done after the animation it should be automatically back to the default state :)) sorry newbie in animation hehe here is my code

```
public GameObject bookLayout;
public GameObject panel;

public void openBook()
{
    if (bookLayout != null)
    {
        Animator animator = bookLayout.GetComponent<Animator>();
        if (animator != null)
        {
            bool isOpen = animator.GetBool("open");
            animator.SetBool("open", !isOpen);
        }
    }
}
```

problem is it only goes back to the default state after I click it ^_^

Comment: Post the code where you call `openBook`, and it might also help to post a screenshot of your animation controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is called an 'Animation Event', and it's actually not that hard to implement.

First, if there isn't already a MonoBehavior script attached to your bookLayout object, add one to it. Then add a **public** function inside of that script whose sole responsibility is to set the state back to default. Let's call this function 'SetStateDefault'. Then make sure bookLayout is selected in the hierarchy and go to Windows -> Animation -> and open up the Animation tab.

Uncollapse the sprites that make up your animation so that you can see them in the timeline. [image]

Click on the button that will take you to the end of the animation
[image]

In this example, the end of the animation is at frame 4. Now click on the 'Add Event' button

[image]

Then in the Inspector, go to the 'Function' dropdown menu and select that public function that we created earlier, the one called 'SetStateDefault'

[image]

Assuming that your 'SetStateDefault' function does what it's supposed to, that should be it. Please let me know if there's anything you weren't clear on.

[image]