# GameObject doesn't reset its position after the animation is finished

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

So i made a animation for my sword in unity, the animation is basically the sword attack, the animation itself works perfectly, BUT when the animation finishes the sword just freezes on the position of the last frame in the animation, and before you ask; yes i do have Animator component on my sword, anyways, if i check the Loop Time option the animation just loops forever, if you have any solution's about the problem be sure to comment or answer about it, anyways, THANKS!

Comment: I believe in Unity there is a way to set the GameObject's Animation's current frame arbitrarily, so when the animation has played you could manually set it back to the first frame. Are you doing this programmatically or only through the Unity user interface? Perhaps this answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54610293/reset-back-to-default-state-after-animation

Comment: i wanted the animation to play when i press left click on my mouse and the code works, i will try to add another keyframe which will reset the swords position anyways thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would make the "loop" in the animaton window. Just copy&paste keys and make sure the first keyframe is the same as the last keyframe of your sword animation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: i made the first and the last keyframes the same but when i play the animation (by pressing left click while in play mode) it just plays one time and it doesn't play again even if i press left click

Answer (score 0):

copy Transform properties of first keyframe and paste to the last keyframe of your sword animation, so that after one loop sword will come to its initial position

Comment: i made the first and the last keyframes the same but when i play the animation (by pressing left click while in play mode) it just plays one time and it doesn't play again even if i press left click, if u want the code be sure to tell me.